# Delivery Pipeline View for Jenkins Pipelines in job dsl

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

How can I create a delivery pipeline view for jenkins pipeline using jobdsl.

All I could find was deliveryPipelineView, which isn't the same view, any information on this would be useful

Answer (score 2):

Delivery Pipeline views for Jenkins pipelines does not seem to be supported by JobDSL at the moment (1.64).

The Job DSL class DeliveryPipelineView only supports traditional jobs with upstream/downstream dependencies. The reason for this is that the Delivery Pipeline plugin uses different views and data models under the hood to render the pipeline views for upstream/downstream jobs and Jenkins pipelines, much due to the different nature of the underlying data models used in Jenkins.

The traditional view, which JobDSL supports will generate a se.diabol.jenkins.pipeline.DeliveryPipelineView configuration, while views supporting Jenkins pipelines are modelled using the se.diabol.jenkins.workflow.WorkflowPipelineView class in the Delivery Pipeline plugin.

Current DeliveryPipelineView template in JobDSL: https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/blob/master/job-dsl-core/src/main/resources/javaposse/jobdsl/dsl/views/DeliveryPipelineView-template.xml#L2

If you append /config.xml on the URL of your view which is based on Jenkins pipelines, you will notice the XML is of the type se.diabol.jenkins.workflow.WorkflowPipelineView.

The solution at the moment would be to handcraft the necessary config.xml and feed it to Jenkins yourself.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the deliveryPipeLineView method create exactly a delivery pipeline view..

Here an exemple :

```
deliveryPipelineView('name-pipeline') {
   description('description-pipeline')
   pipelineInstances(1)
   showAggregatedPipeline()
   columns(1)
   sorting(Sorting.TITLE)
   updateInterval(2)
   enableStartBuild()
   enableManualTriggers()
   showAvatars()
   showChangeLog()
   pipelines {
    component('name', 'init-job')
   }
}
```

See the doc on gitHub for more details : https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Job-DSL-Commands

Comment: That creates a `Delivery Pipeline View`, not a `Delivery Pipeline View For Jenkins Pipelines` (what the OP asked for).  Sadly, I haven't found a way to make it work either.